# How can I link numpy to use MKL as backend?

Tags: python, numpy, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

I have a `numpy` install and it shows no BLAS backend available:

```
(pyrepoux) bash-4.2$ python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec  6 2019, 08:54:18) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.show_config()
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

I can do `pip install mkl` but still the same output as above. How can I link `numpy` to use MKL as BLAS / LAPACK backend?

Comment: Using Intel-optimized version of Python may help (especially an Intel-optimized Anaconda). See [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/distribution-for-python.html). Note that multiple BLAS can conflicts each other. Having only one BLAS installed/seen often save you from some headaches. Alternatively, you can play with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using in intel python. Create an environment with intel python and required packages like intel-mkl, intel-numpy etc.

```
conda create -n <env-name> intelpython3_full python=3.7.3
conda activate <env_name>
pip install mkl
pip install intel-numpy
```

and try importing numpy and running `np.show_config()`

Refer : https://pypi.org/project/mkl/
https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/

The better way is to install the Intel base Toolkit and source the variables. Intel mkl and intel python is available with the kit. You just need to source the environment variables

```
source <basekit-installation-directory>/setvars.sh
```

Installation guide : https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/installation-guide-for-intel-oneapi-toolkits-linux/top.html

You can also try the suggestion provided by Jerome Richard – try setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD path to the mkl library .so file.
Refer : https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/optimizing-without-breaking-a-sweat.html

Comment: thank you but unfortunately there isn't an intel-numpy version for Python 3.7.3 otherwise it would indeed be trivial.

Comment: You can create the environment $ conda create -n idp python=3.7.3 -c intel and install intel numpy. If version 3.7.9 is fine , then installing intelpython_full would be better.